# I've created an app to display a Carousel View, but it wont work in other android version devices

Tags: java, android-studio

This is java file for my carousel view on my carousel activity

```
CarouselView carouselView = findViewById(R.id.supreme);
        carouselView.setPageCount(mImages.length);
     carouselView.setImageListener(new ImageListener() {
        @Override
        public void setImageForPosition(int position, ImageView imageView) {
            imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        }
    });
    carouselView.setImageClickListener(new ImageClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(int position) {
            Toast.makeText(AutoLube_Products.this, mImageTitle[position], 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

This is my xml file for carousel view

```
 <com.synnapps.carouselview.CarouselView
                    android:id="@+id/supreme"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="260dp"
                    app:fillColor="#FFFFFFFF"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:pageColor="#00000000"
                    app:radius="6dp"
                    app:slideInterval="3000"
                    app:strokeColor="#FF777777"
                    app:strokeWidth="1dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="20dp" />
```

My carousel view works only on a pie version thats my main problem, thanks

Comment: Please add some details to your question!

Comment: sorry bout that I'm new here, my carousel view works on my android device which is a pie version, but when i tried to run my app on other version, the carousel activity that supposed to be display a carousel was being stopped and then back to the main activity.